# forgot android key store but i know all the details on it and the password

Tags: android, keystore

accidentally i lost the key store im using to launch an app on the store
i know all the details i wrote on it and the password , n i used the keytool.exe to get the cert details from a certified APK i uploaded to market before
the certification showed me the finger print, serial number and the date
i created a PC app to make pc time freeze at the same time i created the old key
and created another key store
now the date and other info same , but the serial number n finger print keep getting different everytime i create new key
any1 got a solution or on what basis they give the key those details
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. The keystore contains a certificate which is used to digitally sign your apk. Each certificate is completely unique, and cannot be regenerated or recovered from older apks.

Google relies on this because it is extremely secure, and allows them to really reduce the chances that someone can hack your developer account details and upload a malicious apk as an update to your existing app.

For now, you'll have to reupload the app under a different package name with a different key. In the future, please remember to backup your keystore to multiple locations (but do it securely. Don't accidentally commit it into a public version control system. The keystore should be kept private at all times).

Digital signatures are based upon public-key cryptography. You cannot recover a private key given a public key -- that's the whole point of public-key crypto. Such algorithms are based on one-way functions: things that are easy to do but hard to reverse.